# css compatibility width IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Hi I'm having some problem with css to IE7

I want to put some text side-by-side width an image. like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/imgwx.png/

The problem is that in IE7 the text appears below the image.

I have the following HTML code:

```
   <div id="imageArticle"><img="src/here.jpg"></div>
   <div id="contentArticle">TEXT HERE </div>

  #imageArticle {
        float: right;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        position: relative;
    }
#contentArticle {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
}
```

Any suggesstions??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert your image inside #contentArticle and then float it to right

Answer (score 3):

As I undrestood right you should do like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div style="width:200px">
        <img class="myimage" src="test.jpg" width="90" height="90" style="float:right;"/>
        blabla bla blalbalba
        blabla bla blalbalba
        blabla bla blalbalba
        blabla bla blalbalba
        blabla bla blalbalba
        blabla bla blalbalba
        blabla bla blalbalba
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Text and Image side by side](http://login2win.blogspot.com/2010/07/html-css-text-and-image-side-by-side.html)

I've tested it on IE7 and it works fine.